# Postgres Get Multiple Records that have Multiple Records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have five tables: `users`, `public_pictures`, `pictures`, `picture_tags`, `tags`

Given a `user.id`, I want to get all their `pictures` using `public_pictures`, a join table between `users` and `pictures`.

Next, given the result of `pictures` from the previous query, get all the pictures' `tags` using `picture_tags`, a join table between `pictures` and `tags`.

The end result should be an array of `pictures` with a list of the `tags` associated with each picture.

Using a `user.id` I can get all the `picture` records:

```
SELECT * FROM pictures pi
INNER JOIN public_pictures pp
ON pp.picture_id = pi.id
WHERE pp.user_id = userId;
```

Using a `picture.id` I can get all the `tag` records:

```
SELECT * FROM tags ta
INNER JOIN picture_tags pt
ON pt.tag_id = ta.id
WHERE pt.picture_id = pictureId;
```

I just don't know how to use these two queries to do all of the work in one query. When doing the first query, I will have many `picture` records. I want to run the second query for every picture record returned.

Comment: You're missing debug details in your post. Can you share your sample input data, expected output, your query attempt and why it doesn't work properly?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I added some details. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need some kind of query like this

```
SELECT 
    pictures.*,
    ARRAY_AGG(tags.id) AS picture_tags
FROM public_pictures
JOIN pictures ON pictures.id = public_pictures.picture_id
JOIN picture_tags ON picture_tags.picture_id = pictures.id
JOIN tags ON tags.id = picture_tags.tag_id
WHERE public_pictures.user_id = <user id value>
GROUP BY pictures.id
```

Here I used `ARRAY_AGG` to get an array of `tags.id`s for each picture

Comment: This works great except for in one case. If are no `picture_tags` then the entire result is empty compared to returning an empty array for the `tags`. On my app, there could be a case where a picture does not have a tag associated with it

Comment: @user2465134 Make all `JOIN`s to be `LEFT JOIN`s to get pictures without any tags